# Are there only finite many maximal left ideals for a left Artinian ring?

Tags: artin-ring

As in title.
Are there only finite many maximal left ideals for a left Artinian ring?

Comment: Could you please add some motivation? Also, see http://mathoverflow.net/faq#whatquestions

Comment: And please make the body of the question be complete, even if that means you have to repeat part of the title! 

Comment: Have you considered this question for the ring $M_2(\mathbb C)$?

Comment: (Note that the answer is *yes* in the commutative case: this is part of the standard structure theory for Artinian rings.)

Answer (score 6):

Consider the ring $M_2(k)$ of $2\times 2$ matrices over a field $k$, which is Artinian. Can you describe the maximal left ideals?

Answer (score 3):

As indicated by Pete Clark, an Artinian commutative ring has only finitely many maximal ideals.

However, the correct generalization is not the one you seem to expect but the following: *If $A$ is right-Artinian, the set of isomorphism classes of simple right-$A$-modules is finite.*

This implies the commutative case. Assume that $A$ is commutative.
Then, if $S$ is a simple $A$-module, there exists
a maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$ of $A$ such that $S\simeq A/\mathfrak m$;
moreover, $\mathfrak m$ is the annihilator of $S$ so that there is a bijection between isomorphism classes of simple $A$-modules and maximal ideals of $A$.